# Draw a borderless table in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

It appears as though the `PDfPCell` class does have a border property on it but not the `PdfPTable` class.

Is there some property on the `PdfPTable` class to set the borders of all its contained cells in one statement?

Answer (score 3):

Borders are defined at the level of the cell, not at the level of the table. Hence: if you want to remove the borders of the table, you need to remove the borders of each cell.

By default, each cell has a border. You can change this default behavior by changing the border of each cell. For instance: if you create `PdfPCell` objects, you use:

```
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

In case the cells are created internally, you need to change that property at the level of the default cell. See [What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006618/what-is-the-pdfptable-defaultcell-property-used-for)

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

For special borders, for instance borders with rounded corners or a single border for the whole table, or double borders, you can use either cell events or table events, or a combination of both. In Chapter 5 of my book "iText in Action - Second Edition", you'll find [a PDF with double borders](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/press_previews.pdf). See the [PressPreviews](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95) example to see how this was done. Note that all examples from the book were ported to C#. You can find [these examples here](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178).

The official site also has examples where the borders [are dotted lines](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/DottedLineCell), [have rounded corners](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=96), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

iTextSharp has no setBorder() method.

I tried the following:

```
cell.HasBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); // <= this did nothing
cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; // <= this works for me, but if your document's background is not white, you might not like it
cell.BorderWidth = 0; // <= this works like gangbusters
```

So it seems the "safest" way to go is to set BorderWidth to zilch AKA nada.

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: Then you should ask a question, not post a comment, along with what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

```
cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```