# What is the PdfPTable.DefaultCell property used for?

Tags: c#, itext

What is the `DefaultCell` property used for?

The Java documentation for `PdfPTable.getDefaultCell()` reads:

*Gets the default `PdfPCell` that will be used as reference for all the `addCell` methods except `addCell(PdfPCell)`.*

I don't understand it.

The documentation for the .NET library is lacking. The Java one is still documented but again not that well. I usually look up from the Java one because the two API's are symmetrical. But I still don't understand the meaning of this property.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a `PdfPTable`, you add cells.

One way is to create a `PdfPCell` object and to add that cell with the `addCell()` method.

Another way is to use a short-cut: you don't create a `PdfPCell`, but you add a `String` or a `Phrase` to the table with the `addCell()` method. In this case, a `PdfPCell` is created **internally** using **default properties**. You can **change the default properties** by **changing the properties of the default cell**. The default cell is obtained using the `getDefaultCell()` method.

This is what the Javadoc information is about: this default `PdfPCell` will be used as reference for all the `addCell()` methods except `addCell(PdfPCell)`. (Because when adding a `PdfPCell`, the properties of that `PdfPCell` will be used, *not* the properties of the *default* cell.)

This is explained in Chapter 4 of my book ["iText in Action - Second Edition"](http://itextpdf.com/book).